# Majuscule après les deux points

Tags: ponctuation, majuscules

Faut-il mettre une majuscule au début d'une phrase interrogative introduite par les deux points.
Par exemple:

> C’est dans ce cadre que nous nous posons la question suivante : (C)(c)omment savoir que les carottes sont cuites ?

Comment: Une phrase commence par une majuscule et se termine par un point. Il ne convient donc pas d'utiliser de majuscule après les deux points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La première lettre d'une phrase est une majuscule.

Le symbole `:` ne termine pas une phrase, au contraire il la prolonge pour donner une précision sur la partie précédente.

Dans l'exemple donné, il n'y a donc pas lieu de mettre une majuscule après `:` c'est même une faute typographique.

Answer (score 5):

Effectivement, il n'y a pas lieu de mettre une majuscule après les deux points dans l’exemple particulier que vous donnez, mais si votre question n’est pas strictement limitée à votre exemple, il existe, [au Canada au moins](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect7&info0=7#zz7), un cas où une phrase interrogative qui suit les deux points doit commencer par une majuscule :

7 Les guillemets et les citations

7.2.3 Phrase complète

c) En l’introduisant par les deux points

Une citation complète qui est introduite par les deux points commence toujours par une majuscule. Si elle est au milieu de la phrase, elle perd son point final. Si elle est à la fin de la phrase, son point final éclipse celui de la phrase principale :

> Dans un sondage, on a demandé aux gens : « Croyez-vous que la
>   catastrophe aurait pu être évitée? »