# Capitalization in titles and after a colon

Tags: majuscules

Do you capitalize the first word after a colon in French?

> Monsieur Leopold ne pouvait pas venir à moi : il/Il s'était cassé la jambe.

> Madame Arine dit : « J'/j'ai trouvé une châtaigne sur la route. »

What about title capitalization?

> L'histoire du chat qui s'est perdu.

> > L'histoire Du Chat Qui S'est Perdu.

Comment: I suppose you mean *l'histoire du chat qui s'est perdu*.

Comment: Questions should focus on one problem only and you ask  two questions in one. The other question also has an answer: [*Majuscule après les deux points*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12676/358)